# Read and store the multiple value in HashMap Apache POI

Tags: java, hashmap, apache-poi

In Excel I have data like below, where first row is header.

```
           ProductName                  ProductSubType 
    COMPREHENSIVE INSURANCE         COMPREHENSIVE INSURANCE
    COMPREHENSIVE INSURANCE         DRIVER & PASSENGER
    COMPREHENSIVE INSURANCE         THIRD PARTY INSURANCE
    DEBT PROTECTION                 CREDIT LIFE
    DEBT PROTECTION                 RETRENCHMENT
```

Below is the code that I have tried.

```
 XSSFSheet myExcelSheet3 = xssfWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet3");
  XSSFRow xssfRow3 = myExcelSheet3.getRow(0);

    Integer columnIndexKey = null;
    for (Cell cell : xssfRow3) {
        if (cell.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("ProductType")) {
            columnIndexKey = cell.getColumnIndex();
            break;
        }
    }
    Set<String> stringKey = new HashSet<>();
    if (columnIndexKey != null) {
        for (Row row : myExcelSheet3) {
            if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            Cell cell = row.getCell(columnIndexKey);
            stringKey.add(getCellData(xssfWorkbook, cell));
        }
    }
    List<String> stringKeyList = new ArrayList<>(stringKey);
    Collections.sort(stringKeyList);
```

Get the values i.e. ProductSubType as List

```
List<String> stringValue = new ArrayList<>();
        if (columnIndexValue != null) {
            for (Row row : myExcelSheet3) {
                if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                Cell cell = row.getCell(columnIndexValue);
                stringValue.add(getCellData(xssfWorkbook, cell));
            }
        }
```

and finally added the key and values in HashMap

```
 Map<List<String>, List<String>> stringListMap = new HashMap<>();
  stringListMap.put(stringKeyList,stringListValue);
  stringListMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key = "+ k + ", Value = " + v));
```

The output I am getting is

```
Key = [COMPREHENSIVE INSURANCE, DEBT PROTECTION], Value = [COMPREHENSIVE INSURANCE, DRIVER & PASSENGER, THIRD PARTY INSURANCE, CREDIT LIFE, RETRENCHMENT]
```

However I want output in below format.

```
COMPREHENSIVE INSURANCE -> COMPREHENSIVE INSURANCE, DRIVER & PASSENGER, THIRD PARTY INSURANCE
DEBT PROTECTION -> CREDIT LIFE, RETRENCHMENT.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Map<String, List<String>>` instead of `Map<List<String>, List<String>>` and reorder your code like this.

```
//Calculate columnIndexKey and columnIndexValue

Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
if (columnIndexKey != null && comumnIndexValue != null) {
    for (Row row : myExcelSheet3) {
        if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        Cell cell = row.getCell(columnIndexKey);
        Cell valueCell = row.getCell(columnIndexValue);

        String key = getCellData(xssfWorkbook, cell);
        String value = getCellData(xssfWorkbook, valueCell);

        if (!result.contains(key)) {
            result.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        result.get(key).add(value);
    }
}

result.foreach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key = "+ k + ", Value = " + v));
```